ASP.NET Core 8 Blazor : OpenIdConnect save user scope to app database
For testing and fun, I created a default ASP.NET Core 8 Blazor web app with individual accounts for authentication, and I added my keycloak to it. In keycloak, users can have custom attributes, like where they work (cegnev). How can I make that my ASP.NET Core app saves that data to its database?
This is my modified ApplicationUser:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace TesztBlazorAuth.Data
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string cegnev { get; set; }
    }
}

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TesztBlazorAuth.Components;
using TesztBlazorAuth.Components.Account;
using TesztBlazorAuth.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var configuration = builder.Configuration;

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
       .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityUserAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityRedirectManager>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
})
.AddIdentityCookies();

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddSignInManager()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender<ApplicationUser>, IdentityNoOpEmailSender>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = configuration["GoogleAuth:id"];
    options.ClientSecret = configuration["GoogleAuth:secret"];
})
.AddOpenIdConnect("Keycloak", "CorpAuth", options =>
{
    options.Authority = $"{configuration["Keycloak:auth-server-url"]}realms/{configuration["Keycloak:realm"]}";
    options.ClientId = configuration["Keycloak:resource"];
    options.ClientSecret = configuration["Keycloak:credentials:secret"];
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
       {
           ValidateIssuer = true
       };
    
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.Scope.Add("phone");
    options.Scope.Add("cegnev");
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
       .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

// Add additional endpoints required by the Identity /Account Razor components.
app.MapAdditionalIdentityEndpoints();
app.UseAntiforgery();
app.Run();

The users should have the cegnev from keyclaok in the database.

This is what works for me, is there any more simple way?:
.AddOpenIdConnect("Keycloak", "CorpAuth", options =>
{
    options.Authority = $"{configuration["Keycloak:auth-server-url"]}realms/{configuration["Keycloak:realm"]}";
    options.ClientId = configuration["Keycloak:resource"];
    options.ClientSecret = configuration["Keycloak:credentials:secret"];
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
       {
           ValidateIssuer = true
       };

    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.Scope.Add("phone");
    options.Scope.Add("cegnev");

    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("cegnev", "cegnev");

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = async context =>
        {
            var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
            var userManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            var signInManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();

            var email = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
            var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

            if (user == null)
            {
                user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = email,
                    Email = email,
                    cegnev = claimsIdentity.FindFirst("cegnev")?.Value
                };

                var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var cegnevClaim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst("cegnev")?.Value;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cegnevClaim) && user.cegnev != cegnevClaim)
                {
                    user.cegnev = cegnevClaim;
                    await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                }
            }
        }
    };
});


There are eventhandlers in AddOpenIdConnect that you can plug into, to capture all the claims from KeyCloak and then save them to your local database.
See the OpenIdConnectEvents Class as documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents?view=aspnetcore-8.0
Here's an example:
  .AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
    {
        //Additional config snipped
        o.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
            {
                ...
            }
        };
    });

